# Template Absolute and Relative paths

Tags: magento-1.7

Template Absolute and Relative paths. What does that mean?

Comment: This is a bit sparse of a question. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**An absolute path** is from the upper most level of the directory tree. Ie. `/` or `C:\`

Eg. `/home/sonassi/www/index.php`

**A relative path** is relative to the current working directory. In the case of a web server, that would be the document root. Ie. In PHP `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

In the example above the document root is `/home/sonassi/www` - making the relative path to `index.php` just `./index.php` or `index.php`. The leading `./` just denotes the current directory.

---

**You should always use relative paths for cross-platform compatibility**

Eg. Magento uses a relative path for the `./app/Mage.php` include in `index.php` - which means even if you change server, it will still look only in the `app` subdirectory for the file.

But if they had defined an absolute path, eg. `/home/sonassi/www/app/Mage.php` - then it means if you ever moved servers - and the document root was no longer `/home/sonassi/www` - then the hardcoded path would no longer be valid.

**Absolute paths have their place** - but as far as Magento templates are concerned (ie. definitions in XML files, they should always be relative)